# .env with debugging breakpoint using vscode and dotenv npm

Tags: node.js, debugging, npm, visual-studio-code, dotenv

I'm using a nodejs server side api, setting up environment variables with  **dotenv**  npm package, and running the code from npm scripts in **package.json** as below:

```
"scripts": {
   "local": "cross-env NODE_ENV=local nodemon ./bin/www"
}
```

What I need is to configure my .vscode/launch.json file.

Currently it looks like:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": []
}
```

Kindly guide me. Thanks,
Gopal.R

- [dotenv npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)
- Visual Studio Code - [Launch configurations](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387)

Answer (score 16):

You would want to set the [`.dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) environmental variable up like:

```
NODE_ENV=local
```

Then to require it in your debugger, you would want to add it into your [`launch.json`](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387) configurations like:

```
"runtimeArgs": [
    "--require=dotenv/config"
]
```

Here it is in context:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [ 
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch | local with dotenv config",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/www/your_script.js",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--require=dotenv/config"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

`--require=dotenv/config` is the equivalent of running `require('dotenv').config()` in your script or `node -r dotenv/config your_script.js` if you're using the command line.

Here are some alternate examples of where environmental variables can be placed in the config.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [ 
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch | local using env file",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/www/your_script.js",
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch | local without dotenv",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/www/your_script.js",
            "env" : {
                "NODE_ENV" : "local"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Note**: This code hasn't been tested... so feedback is welcome.

Comment: `"envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"` worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question for typescript debugging and I found answer here. Need to specify `runtimeArgs` and `envFile` parameters to make it work.

Example of `launch.json` for **TypeScript** debugging:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/server.ts",
            "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/built/**/*.js"
            ],
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--require=dotenv/config"
            ],
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"
        }
    ]
}
```