# In VS Code-debugger, how do I use envFile in launch.json for nodejs?

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, dotenv

I'm trying to run the debugger in VS Code on my nodejs application.  I'm using an .env file to store environment variables that I later call with process.env..  When I looked up the VS Code docs for the launch.json, it mentions the envFile option to load the the .envFile.  Unfortunately, this is not loading the files when I run the debugger.

launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "RegressionTestSuite",
            "autoAttachChildProcesses": true,
            "program": "node ${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js",
            "args": [
            ],
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"
        },
    ]
}
```

.env:

```
export SCREEN_SIZE_WIDTH='1366';
export SCREEN_SIZE_HEIGHT='768';
```

When I run the VS Code debugger, there are no environment variables from my .env file.  How should I be calling the .env file in the launch.json?

Comment: At first glance, it looks like your `.env` file isn't setup properly (as mentioned in the answer below). Here are some alternate options using dotenv with runtimeArgs and envFile - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58127078/5623301 - my debugger wouldn't work with the below code but these did.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use the [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package to load your `.env` file, as it can be used by people who aren't using VS Code as well. If you want to include it in your VS Code config, you could do:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "RegressionTestSuite",
        "autoAttachChildProcesses": true,
        "program": "node -r dotenv/config ${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js",
        "args": []
     },
   ]
}
```

Your problem could also be that your `.env` file should not contain `export` and semi-colons, as it is not a JavaScript/shell file:

```
SCREEN_SIZE_WIDTH=1366
SCREEN_SIZE_HEIGHT=768
```

Answer (score 13):

You can try this to load the env file.

```
 {
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "pwa-node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\Chat\\server.js",
      "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}\\Chat\\.env"
    }
  ]
}
```